# Is there a way to assign the fields of a ctypes structure using a loop?

Tags: python, struct, ctypes

I want to generate a `ctypes.Structure` from a dict, and the only way I see how to do that is to assign the values 1 element at a time.

```py
import ctypes


class MyStructure(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('a', ctypes.c_uint16),
                ('b', ctypes.c_double)]


def generate_structure_from_dict(my_dict):
    my_structure = MyStructure()
    my_structure.a = my_dict['a']
    my_structure.b = my_dict['b']
    return my_structure
```

However, not only does this produce ugly code when `MyStructure` has 20+ fields, it also means that every time I change my structure, I have to remember to change my `generate_structure_from_dict` function.

Is there any way to populate a `ctypes.Structure` through a loop? Ideally a loop that was able to specify the correct key in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setattr:

```
for name in my_dict:
    setattr(my_structure, name, my_dict[name])
```